# heroku and codeigniter www.mysite.com wont work while mysite.com does

Tags: codeigniter, heroku

Hi I am developing in Codeigniter on the Heroku server.

So when I have my base_url to be "mysite.com", i.e:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://mysite.com/";
```

I am able to access my website perfectly except for a bug with my $_POST variables which are empty and the possible solution is to change the base_url to be "www.mysite.com", i.e:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.mysite.com/";
```

However, when I apply this change I am not able to navigate through my website. In more detail: When I go to the URL http://www.mysite.com/home I successfully see my login page, but when I attempt to login I get a heroku message:

Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

My logs are:

```
←[36m2013-07-03T04:41:39.297151+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [Wed Jul 03 04:41:38 2013]
 [error] [client 10.93.18.63] File does not exist: /app/www/images/http:
←[36m2013-07-03T04:41:39.824984+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 10.93.89.126 - - [03/Jul/2
013:04:41:08 +0000] "POST /index.php/pages/login_check/ HTTP/1.0" 200 2497
←[36m2013-07-03T04:41:39.824984+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 10.93.18.63 - - [03/Jul/20
13:04:41:38 +0000] "GET /images/http://www_100_200.jpg HTTP/1.0" 404 227
←[33m2013-07-03T04:41:38.847357+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H12 desc
="Request timeout" method=POST path=/index.php/pages/login_check/ host=www.mysite
.com fwd="184.74.137.176" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 byte
s=0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quick check if this works `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`